# jquery validation plugin disable error messages but keep highlights

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I don't need error messages from jquery validation plugin, how can i disable them?

I saw this workaround here a lot, but it also removes highlights, so I guess it doesn't work for the new version.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return false;
},
```

What else can I do?

Comment: This plugin? What plugin?

Comment: jquery validate i said it already

Comment: Yeah, it's not like there are 300 jquery validation plugins out there :)

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ it is really called like this:P

Comment: haha :) okay then, I'm having a look

Comment: From the example on this page http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/marketo/, you want to hide the red line that appears at the top in case of fail? It has an `.error` class, so just add `.error{ display:none; }` to your CSS. If it doesn't work, try  `.error{display:none!important; }`

Comment: oops, use `div.error`, otherwise it will also hide all the input that also have the `.error` class

Comment: sounds, good. but this is kind of too global solution

Comment: That also only applies to [the one demo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/marketo/), since any CSS styling is **not** included with the plugin and the default error container is a `label`.

Answer (score 0):

**[This](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) is still the correct code** for preventing the validation messages from being inserted onto the page.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    return false;
},
```

> I saw this workaround here a lot, but it also removes highlights,

**The plugin does not remove, nor create, any "highlights"**.  Any/all styling is external to the plugin and totally up to your own designs.

Aside from simply assigning an `error` or `valid` class to the invalid or valid elements, the plugin has nothing to do with CSS and does not include any CSS properties.  It's up to you to assign or not assign CSS properties to the `error` and `valid` classes.

Otherwise, the plugin gives you options called [`errorClass`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorclass) and [`validClass`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#validclass) that allows you to change the class names from `error` and `valid` into whatever you wish.

> What else can I do?

Inspect the DOM before and after removal of the error messages.  What are the differences?  Fix those.